# How come I can call IsNullOrWhiteSpace without specifying string class

Tags: c#, extension-methods

During my research I found something interesting about `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.

This is an extension method but I used to use it as `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.

Somewhere I found I can call it without specifying `string` class:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var auth = req.Headers["Authorization"];
        if (!IsNullOrWhiteSpace(auth))
        {
...
```

How it's possible and why it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you'll find this at the top of the file:

```cs
using static System.String;
```

The feature of [*using static directives*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-static) was introduced in C# 6, and allows you to use any static member of the specified class without qualification.

Comment: Yes, I have that using. So that's the trick. It's very handy. Thank you!